# How to update specific attributes from restricted model using Best_In_Place and Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, best-in-place

How can say a 'teacher' update only certain attribute of a model (say model 'book') while he/she could not update the other attributes of that model when using both Cancan and Best_In_Place. I understand that attribute-authorization is not yet supported in Cancan as it is still under development in 2.0 so the first thing I thought was to use something like this:

```
cannot :all, Book
if is_teacher?
    can :update_certain_attribute, Book
end
```

But since I wanted to use Best_In_Place, my preliminary research tells me that I could only use attributes for Best_In_Place update 
like below

```
<%= best_in_place @book, :certain_attribute, :type => :input %>
```

and not methods :

```
<%= best_in_place @book, :update_certain_attribute, :type => :input %>
```

What's the best way to deal with this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated as talking about 2 things

This will ensure that the variable is attribute accessible, and so if it is updated uses best_in_place, the model / controller won't allow the variable to be actually updated

For this I think you'll need to look at dynamic attribute accessible. Ryan has a nice cast on this here http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible

To have a condition using cancan on best_in_place you can use the following code

again this doesn't help for a specific attribute, but in conjunction with dynamic attribute accessible will ensure the variable won't be changed

Comment: Hmmm I'm a little bit confused how I could implement that to this :) Briefly looking at it makes me think that I won't be using best_in_place anymore... or am I mistaken? :) Anyway, thanks I'll check up on this in-depth later at home :)